# How to compile a program to make it capable to use >4GB memory on 32-bit Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, fedora

The whole code is written in C, C++, and Fortran. 
Is it possible to make it to use more than 4GB memory.
Now it is always crashed when it reaches 3GB memory.

If it is possible, how to set up the compiling options (or configure flags)?

We can use gcc, g++, ...or intel compilers

our OS: Fedora 12 x32

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips : 5319.72
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Comment: The kernel does have PAE support, too.


 2.6.32.26-175.fc12.i686.PAE #1 SMP i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: PAE support only means the kernel can address that much memory, not the individual processes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you are hitting the limit that

```
R> 2^32
[1] 4294967296
```

which is your 4 gb limit.  So you simply cannot index beyond *for a single application*, no matter what the OS.

This is one of the reasons many of us switched to 64 bit versions of our OSs. Linux has supported this since the late 1990s. Just switch to FC (or Ubuntu or ...) in 64bit.

One possible alternative is installing more RAM (which Linux will handle) and segmenting your task over several instances of the application, effectively running it in parallel. But that may not be worth the trouble...

Comment: I thought Windows OS total, could get past 2^32, but individual processes were still stuck at 2^32?  Now I have to go look it up :-)

Comment: Yes, I was imprecise in the first revision and have amended it.  The kernel can see more than 4gb, but each running process is still limited.

Comment: On earlier versions of 32 bit Windows it was possible to use PAE for up to 16 GByte. MS has disabled it in modern Windows, because it didn't work reliable anyway because the drivers need to support it too. IHMO it still works in linux though. In theory you could use PAE on a single process too, but you won't have a linear address space anymore.

Comment: Address Windowing Extensions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows could be used to allow a single process to work with large amounts of physical memory (>4GB) - but with the restriction that it could only access a chunk at a time using a "window" in the normal 2GB process address space.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if you put a file in a tmpfs filesystem (or hugetlbfs) and in your program map small (1 - 2 GB) pieces of it at a time, you can work with more than 4 GB of data at once.

The map operations aren't all that fast so you will take a performance hit if you jump through your memory too randomly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to partition its working set into chunks of < 3 GB, and handle each chunk in a separate process. Connect the processes by pipes or sockets.

This is pretty similar to developing it into a network/cluster application, which might not be a bad idea if you want scalability.

Comment: are you talking about making it a distributed application ? where several instances will talk to each other ? and get the job done ?

Comment: IIRC before switching to 64 bits, Adobe Premiere CS4 also uses this technique for utilizing the large memory size

Answer (score 1):

32-bit integers can't count higher than 4Gb:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/32-bit-os-and-4gb-memory-limit-707762/