# Allocate large memory using x64 system with x86 application in c++

Tags: c++, qt, memory, 64-bit, mingw32

I have a problem and couldn't find a solution (because of the lack of knowledge).

The problem is that my application (written in `c++` compiled with `mingw` `x86` using `Qt` 5.3.2) allocates blocks of memory which in summary should accommodate from 7.5 to 8.5 GB (I have precomputed this using calc). Each block is 1 MB.

Application allocates memory in a cycle, one iteration allocates 1 MB of memory.
I have only 8 GB of memory but when I use monitors to see when it stops allocating I see that it doesn't depend how much memory is accomodated at the moment of starting the app.

It always stops allocating when the app allocates 4 GB and it doesn't depend on the fact that there is still 2 free GB in the system (before start I have nearly 6 GB free of 8) or there isn't.

So I can't understand why it happens in such way but I think that it is because of x86 structure of the app.

But I need to use the app on x86 systems too (I know that there can't be such x86 system with more than 4 GB).

How can I solve the problem?

I prefere ways that would save the x86 structure of the app and allow it to allocate more than 4 GB.
   But if there is no such solution I would be made to use x64 structure of the app.

Comment: Just build separate versions of your application for 64-bit and 32-bit systems. 32-bit applications simply cannot use more than four gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626090/how-to-compile-a-program-to-make-it-capable-to-use-4gb-memory-on-32-bit-linux

Comment: It's not duplicate. The OP wants to allocate more than 4GB or memory which is impossible on x86

Comment: @Googie sorry I looked at the link and the `>` sign was removed. However that link is about Linux and this is for Windows

Comment: There is AWE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions although that will be a lot of work just like the 2 processes method. I would and have done for a long time as the first comment says. I mean build separate 64bit and 32 bit applications although these days the 32 bit compiles do not happen frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your application stops filling memory after 4 GB is because it is using *32-bit pointers*. With 32 bits, you can only represent `2^32`, or *4,294,967,296* bytes of memory. Physically speaking, you *cannot* fill up more space.

More specifically, your program can also be given **maximum** 4 GB of pages from the OS, so using 2 32-bit pointers won't help.

Unfortunately this means that you have to make the switch to 64-bit, which would allow a lot more memory locations to be addressed.

Comment: An alternative solution could be (as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626090/how-to-compile-a-program-to-make-it-capable-to-use-4gb-memory-on-32-bit-linux) to change the application design and use multiple processes that communicate with each other and they can together use more memory. It's more difficult, but if switching to 64 bit is not an option, then this is the only other way I can think of.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but it seems like going into far more trouble than simply compiling in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that I'll try to recompile in x64, but the idea with multyprocess app is very interesting too.